# Creating View with Condititional Criteria

Tags: oracle, sql-view

In an Oracle Database version 11g I want to create or replace a view BADGES with the following characteristics:

(1) The view will contain two columns: EMP_ID (NUMBER(9), BADGE_NO(NUMBER(13)).

(2) The view will get data from table Public_View’s following columns: EMP_ID (NUMBER(9)), BLDG_CD(NUMBER(4)), OFFSET_ID(NUMBER(10)).

(3) In the view BADGE_NO is the concatenation of BLDG_CD and OFFSET_ID.

(4) Now the part I am having trouble with: When OFFSET_ID < 1000000 (less than 1 million), I want to left pad OFFSET_ID with 0 (zero) for a total of 7 characters. When OFFSET_ID >= 1000000 (equal to or greater than 1 million), I want to left pad OFFSET_ID with 0 (zero) for a total of 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition on the sign value in the length of the offset ID minus 7, **SIGN(length(OFFSET_ID)-7)**

```
SELECT DECODE(SIGN(length(OFFSET_ID)-7), -1, LPAD(OFFSET_ID, 7, '0'), LPAD(OFFSET_ID, 8, '0'))   
FROM your_table;
```

You can also use the CASE statement if you want,(e.g. CASE **SIGN(length(OFFSET_ID)-7)** )